# Change Post Title Edit Box

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox

When editing a post, the title field displays the placeholder "Enter title here" (it's actually a label element that's made to look like a placeholder attribute, but whatever). I have a custom post type where I'm using the title for something specific and I want to make it clearer what it is. Is there any way to modify this field or the way it's outputted?

I couldn't find any filter for this. I could hook after it with [`edit_form_after_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions), but I want to modify the field itself. I could remove the title field and use my own, but I want it to have the appearance of WordPress's title field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add following code to your `functions.php` in the Theme-folder.
Change the `Custom Post Type`(movie) name and the `title` to your wishes.

```
function wpse213979_new_title_text( $title, $post ){ 
   if  ( 'movie' == $post->post_type ) { // Movie is the cpt name
      $title = 'Enter movie name'; // The text you want to be shown
   }

   return $title;
}
add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'wpse213979_new_title_text', 10, 2 );
```

> The [code
>   reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enter_title_here/)

Hope this is what you where looking for.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That filter isn't listed on the [reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). Is there any page that has it and filters like it (besides the [complete list of hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/))?

Comment: Ehm, to be honest except [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php/page/2/) I can't find it neither. So, computer says _no_ .